Bias in simulation samples low frequency event at higher rates
I am trying to simulate a dataset of x trials and y subjects, where every trial can be one of 3 categorical vars, associated with a unique probability. For every subject and trial, I also want to add noise to these probabilities, so every subject has a unique probability vector, and every trial is noisy.
Original state probabilities are [.1,.4,.5]. To add subject and trial noise, I generate random noise per subject and per trial, then I sum state probabilities with subject noise and trial noise. Then I use this new vector as alpha parameters to a dirichlet distribution to generate noisy subject and trial state probabilities. Then I use these to sample from a multinomial distribution.
However, as I increase the noise of trials and subjects, there is a bias. If I sample with low noise, eventually I will sample the states at the original probabilities. If I sample with higher noise, there appears a bias where the .1 probability will be sampled at higher rates (~.12). How can I account for that?
Code
library(tidyverse)
library(DirichletReg)

log_odds <- function(probs) {
  return(log(probs / (1 - probs)))
}

prob_from_log <- function(logs){
  return( exp(logs)/ (1+exp(logs)))
}

sample_from_dirichlet <- function(alpha_params) {
  return(rdirichlet(n = 1, alpha = alpha_params))
}

sample_from_multinomial <- function(prob_vector) {
  sample <- rmultinom(n = 1, size = 1, prob = unlist(prob_vector))
  return(which(sample==1))
}

initial_p <- c(.1,.4,.5)    # initial state probabilities
 
n_trials <- 100             # number of trials to consider
n_subjects <- 100           # maximum sample size to consider

subj_int <- .5              # subject-varying intercept in log-odds
error <- .5                 # residual error per trial  in log-odds


# create a dataframe with the trials
items <- data.frame(trial_id = rep(seq(n_trials),1), 
                    condition = rep(c("base"), c(n_trials)) )

# create a dataframe with subject noise
subjects <- data.frame(subj_id = seq_len(n_subjects), 
                       subj_intercept = I(lapply(1:n_subjects, function(x) rnorm(n=length(initial_p), mean=0, sd=subj_int))))

trials <- crossing(subjects, items) %>% # combine items and subjects dataframe
  mutate(e_si =I(lapply(1:nrow(.), function(x) rnorm(n=length(initial_p), mean=0, sd=error))), # create trial specific noise
         initial_p_values= I(rep(list(initial_p), nrow(.))),  # add probability vector
         log_p= I(lapply(initial_p_values, log_odds)),  # convert probabilities to log odds 
         total_noise = map2(subj_intercept, e_si, ~ .x + .y), # combine sources of noise (subject+trial)
         final_log =  map2(log_p, total_noise, ~ .x + .y), # combine log odds vector and noise
         final_p_non_sum = I(lapply(final_log, prob_from_log)), # return to probabilities
         alpha_params = I(lapply(final_p_non_sum, function(p) p * 1000)),  # scale probabilities to use as alpha parameters in dirichlet
         dirichlet_sample = I(lapply(alpha_params, sample_from_dirichlet)), # sample probabilities that sum to 1
         sample_state = lapply(dirichlet_sample,sample_from_multinomial)) # sample from multinomial distributions
         
trials %>% 
  group_by(sample_state) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  mutate(perc=n/(n_trials*n_subjects)) -> res

print(res)
```


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Edited to clarify
